# Stuck at NoSuchElement exception in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a form which requires its data consists of textbox, combo box etc and finally i need to save.

Please find below outer HTML pattern of save button:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnEditSave" value="Save" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnEditSave&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;vgExhibitor1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnEditSave" class="green-btn">
```

The problem is when I use id /name/xpath with this element for the first time for example, to get the validation on clicking on save without filling data on the form, it's working fine but when I fill all data and do the same it does not save rather it throws

```
`**"Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element"**`
```

Please suggest me on this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your quick reply on this. The issue is that the form has one iframe. Before saving the complete form I did not switch to the default content from child to parent so elements were not able to be picked up by selenium api.

Answer (score 0):

Might be xpath of save button gets changed after first submission, try to shorten your xpath and eliminate unwanted div tag if any, try using following xpath

```
//input[@value='Save']
```